# Two websites with semi-similar keywords on same IP server / SEO affecting SERPS

Tags: seo, search-results, negative-seo

Two websites have semi-similar (main) keywords

- 1 brand site /w keyword "Superman shoes"
- and 1 retail site named shoes.com

They both run on the same server/hosting, same SSL cert, comparable design, same NS, similar DNS data and same IP.

I understand from some blogs and rumours that this can confuse search engine like Google and Bing. And the keyword "shoes" in this instance is not been giving the SERP that one would expect for both sites. (The reason why search engines do is that some companies have tried to obtain both SERP 1, 2 and 3 listings with similar websites but different domains. In this case though it is legit.).

**Now my question**: what would one have to do to separate these two websites so they are treated as separate websites? (where changing what they stand for, or what they are is not possible)

One advice I got was: set-up a separate IP for the two websites. But is there more I should worry about and organize when I do this "separation"? 
(the server software and NS I cannot change)

I appreciate your help / advice

Comment: Won't make a difference... look at Stack Exchange, 100's of stacks listed under same whois details, including IP and name servers. The only negative SEO that can be received by having the same IP is link schemes done on a big scale and they are all unrelated. Sister sites under the same ownership regardless of the content are related.

Comment: *I understand from some blogs and rumours that this can confuse search engine like Google and Bing.* Huh?? If you see cr@p like this leave the site immediately. It is total B.S.

Answer (score 0):

Google said recently that if 2 websites with similar content are on the same IP that one of them will see a rank drop.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters! It would be good to include a source for that if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Agree           Would be Nice